# Does spacing matter in reference/dereference symbols?

Tags: c++

I was looking over some code and noticed this:

`typedef T * iterator;`

I was wondering if this is different from `typedef T* iterator`?

Comment: FWIW, if you switch to the `using` syntax, it becomes much easier to avoid this confusion: `using iterator = T*` or `using iterator = T *` or `using iterator =  whatever else`

Comment: No, it doesn't make any difference at all. While the target doesn't mention `typedef` specifically, the rules are identical.